# Preg_Match(): compilation failed unknown property name

Tags: php, errors, regex, characters

I'm having a problem with a wordpress theme I bought but their support is terrible. On every post page, I receive this error:

> Warning: `preg_match()`: Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p at offset 7 in `/nfs/c11/h03/mnt/206871/domains/ghldn.com/html/wp-content/themes/hive/inc/template-tags.php` on line 230
>       `data-first_letter="A">`

I can see that the problem is in template_tags.php line 230, which is the following:

```
preg_match( '/[\p{Xan}]/u', $content, $results );
```

I can't see any problem there. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Xan is a georgian letter as I can find in Google, but it's not a valid Unicode Script for RegEx, you can find a list of the Unicode Scripts here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Maybe try using another one than Xan, maybe Georgian:

```
preg_match( '/[\p{Georgian}]/u', $content, $results );
```

Let me know how that goes.